# How can I log out of Teams account from old organization (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome

Microsoft teams has this annoying "feature" that when I click a teams meeting link, it redirects to my organization page. Except I'm not associated with that organization anymore, and guess what, there is no button to log out, only to log in:

[image]

[image]

Also, there are no cookies in this specific page, so trying to remove them is futile. I figured the cookies are for `teams.microsoft.com`, but as soon as I enter this page, it instantly redirects me to the infamous past-organization page, so I can't open dev tools there.

**How can I delete these cookies for that page specifically, in Chrome, without deleting all my browser data?**

Comment: Have you tried wiping the Teams data contained within AppData?

Comment: @Ramhound but this is on the web version, not the Teams app

Comment: Please add more details like the name and version of the operative system that you are using and if you have Office related apps installed in computer like Excel, Work, Skype, etc.

Comment: Teams web app has a surprising amount of interaction, in my experience, with the "thick client" files. You should check your local client files, as Ramhound suggested.

Comment: I'm using Windows. My teams is installed on AppData folder, at least that's where the launcher points to. If I delete that folder, I'm pretty sure I will lose my local teams App

Comment: edit: I tried removing from `roaming` folder, which is where `%appdata%\Microsoft\Teams` points to, still didn't work

Comment: @Bersan - I thought you were using the web application not the desktop application? That folder isn’t applicable to the web application.

Comment: Im using web app, but I also have the desktop app..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to clean all browser data, including cookies, for the problem to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows you can look out for credentials saved in the [Microsoft Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0) within the Web- or Windows Credentials for a microsoft / teams entry and remove it manually.

Comment: Removed all Teams credentials, didn't work...